# How to redirect xargs -P output to individually named files

Tags: bash, redirect

Fundamentally, I want to do something like:

```
find . -type f -print0 | xargs -0 -P 3 blahblahcommand > `mktemp`.blah
```

(not sure where the backticks went around `mktemp`.)

or perhaps `blahblahcommand` allows the specification of an output file:

```
find . -type f -print0 | xargs -0 -P 3 blahblahcommand -o `mktemp`.blah
```

So that as the 3 processes are running (or max of 3 rather), each individual blahblahcommand output is going into a unique file.  But mktemp is evaluated once, and of course, the output of blahblahcommand is stomped on.

blahblahcommand does not have support to generate a uniquely defined filename unfortunately.

Is there an easy way to do this in bash?

Individually is trivial, but I am not enough of a shell programmer to figure out how to make this work like I want.  Any tips appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use GNU `parallel` instead of `xargs`:

```sh
readarray -t files < <(find . -type f -print0 | parallel -0 -X -P3 --files blahblahcommand)
```

will save the output of executions of `blahblahcommand file1 file2 file3 ... fileN` in temporary files and store their names in the `files` array for further use.

Comment: That looks like it would work.  Unfortunately, GNU parallel doesn't seem to be installed in this environment (synology NAS).  I'm going to look for a package and see if it can be added with Entware or something.